# Can't use a button in embedded website. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have embedded an website **inside another website** using iframe..
`<iframe src=..">..`
Inside the embedded website there is a copy button. When I use it in website(without embed) it works. But when I use it in iframe it doesn't..

My button code:
`<button onclick="copy()">copy</button>`
Js:

```
function copy() {
  let copyText = document.getElementById("resu");
  
  copyText.select(); 
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value.replace(/A  /, "A ")).then(function() {
  alert("Copied to clipboard.");
}, function(err) {
  alert("Could not copy text.");
});
  }
```

What's wrong??

---

**Edit**: This problem was solved by using `<iframe src=".." allow="clipboard-read; clipboard-write;">` .. Thanks❤️

Comment: nothing in what you've shown seems to be inherently wrong ... what errors do you get in the browser console?

Comment: are the `<button`  and `copy` function and the `resu` element in the same document/window (whatever you want to call it) - I suspect at least one of those 3 things is not in the same document, and, if the iframe is not the same domain as the containing page it's in, then you can't do that, at all. For security reasons

Comment: @Bravo it is in the same document..

Comment: what is "it" ... the butto, the function and the resu element? that's not an "it", that would be "they are all in the same document" - in which case the existence of an iframe should be irrelevant - and I can't even see a point in embedding such an iframe